# meaning of the phrase "I would know" not in a condtional sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from a [song](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/katyperry/hotncold.html) by Katy Perry. Here is the part:

> You change your mind like a girl changes clothes
>   Yeah, you PMS like a b**** **I would know**.

That doesn't seem to be a conditional sentence and I cannot think of any connoted one.

Comment: I wonder why are you trying to analyze conditional sentences by looking at Katy Perry lyrics.

Comment: I just heard the song and was confused by the use of "would" there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following conversation between an older brother and  younger one:

> Mom!  Dmytro took a swig out of the whisky bottle.
>    -- **How would you know**, you little twerp? You were in the bathtub with your rubber ducky.

A wooden paraphrase of the modal **would** there is something like "What circumstances enabled you to know this, since you can not have seen me do it?" It is a kind of *irrealis* in that it disputes the truth or reality of the assertion **you will know**.  How is it possible?

And as the question **How would you know?** asks incredulously about the conditions or circumstances, the assertion **I would know** alludes to specific conditions or circumstances that justify the earlier claim, and as an afterthought it is like a preemptive answer to the challenge **How would *you* know?**

> ... you PMS like a b****    — I would know

And those circumstances are *it takes one to know one*.  The Katy Perry lyric **I would know** in other words says "I do the same myself and therefore have no trouble recognizing that behavior when I see it".

> You little twerp, you're such a liar!
>   -- You would know, whisky-breath!

That is, you know a liar when you see one because you yourself are a liar, whisky-breath.

Answer (score 2):

The song title is 'Hot N Cold' (='Hot and Cold').

The phrase 'I would know' is on a line by itself:

> You change your mind like a girl changes clothes
>   Yeah, you PMS like a bitch
>   **I would know**
>   And you overthink, always speak cryptically
>   I should know that you're no good for me

The theme of the song is the singer's resentment of the addressed (male) person's mood swings and emotional unpredictability. To 'blow hot and cold' is a idiom meaning to be alternately warm and friendly, and cold and distant, without any apparent reason for changing from one to the other. 'To PMS' appears to mean 'to act like a woman who is suffering from Pre-Menstrual Syndrome (PMS)'. Symptoms of this include irritability and mood changes.

The singer says 'I would know' meaning 'I am very likely to know about PMS because I suffer (or have suffered) from it myself'. "Would" here is a modal verb referring to probability, to what is very likely.

> Would modal verb (PROBABILITY) ​ also 'd used to refer to what is very
>   likely:
>
> "The guy on the phone had a Southern accent." "That would be Tom."

[Would (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would)

'Like a bitch' is a double meaning - 'like a bitch' can mean both 'like an especially annoying woman (a "bitch")' and also 'very much, particularly in a bad or unwelcome way' - 'I cut my hand and it hurt like a bitch.' Needless to say, there is much about the language in the song that may be considered offensive or annoying by many people, because it trivialises, belittles, and stereotypes women (and men as well). Also, it trivialises mental illness (later, she says "Got a case of a love bipolar").